# Filter rows based on values in a column

Tags: r

How can I filter out the rows in which the value in a specific column of the matrix is above a certain value. For instance how do I filter the rows in the below matrix where `logCPM` is above 0.2?

```
> mydata

         logFC     logCPM          LR     PValue       FDR
1  0.552704905 0.18660575 2.805573421 0.09393725 0.1744389
2  0.179752394 0.12956983 0.264209389 0.60724288 0.7164197
3  0.135260378 0.99331911 0.334612036 0.56295589 0.6789419
4  0.007554301 0.66189664 0.001413451 0.97000988 0.9809448
5 -0.107374125 2.56150056 0.251272726 0.61618033 0.7237010
6  0.062867911 0.04769834 0.018075575 0.89305036 0.9300404
```

Comment: `dat[dat$logCPM > 0.2,]`. The downvote is because I think there is a huge amount of question like this, a little effort at least in searching.

Comment: @akrun, oh you are very right. I forget it and I assumed (mistakingly) it was a data frame.

Comment: Sorry, its a data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 mydata[mydata[,'logCPM']>0.2,]
```

Comment: its a data frame, sorry

Comment: why is there a `,` after `0,2`? I get the first `,` before `logCPM` but the second one is throwing me off...

Comment: @dre  The `mydata[,'logCPM']` is to subset the 'logCPM' column as  a vector, then create a logical index `> 0.2`, and this is used as to subset the rows `,]`  Note that in `R`, it is `[row,column]` and if there are no `,`, by default, it will parse as column index

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mydata[mydata$logCPM > 0.2,]
```